# What does Python optimization (-O or PYTHONOPTIMIZE) do?

Tags: python, optimization, python-3.x

The docs only say that Python interpreter performs "basic optimizations", without going into any detail. Obviously, it's implementation dependent, but is there any way to get a feel for what type of things could be optimized, and how much run-time savings it could generate?

Is there any downside to using -O?

The only thing I know is that -O disables `assert`, but presumably one shouldn't use `assert` for things that could still go wrong in production.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the use of Python's basic optimizations mode? (`python -O`)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693088/what-is-the-use-of-pythons-basic-optimizations-mode-python-o)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In Python 2.7, `-O` has the following effect:

- the byte code extension changes to `.pyo`
- [sys.flags.optimize gets set to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17317851/6650102)
- `__debug__` is False
- asserts don't get executed

In addition `-OO` has the following effect:

- [sys.flags.optimize gets set to 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17317851/6650102)
- doc strings are not available

To verify the effect for a different release of CPython, grep the source code for `Py_OptimizeFlag`.

Link to official documentation: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/modules.html#compiled-python-files

Comment: Is there any downside to the -O flag apart from missing on the built-in debugging information?

Comment: I've seen many python modules that assume docstrings are available, and would break if that optimization level is used, for instance at the company where I work, raw sql is placed in docstrings, and executed by way of function decorators (not even kidding).  Somewhat less frequently, `assert` is used to perform logic functions, rather than merely declare the invariant expectations of a point in code, and so any code like that would also break.

Comment: @max: if you go through the complete list of semantical changes above: do you consider any of them a "downside"? If not, there are no downsides. I personally consider it a disadvantage that the name of byte code files changes - it contributes to disk clutter. Notice that "missing built-in debugging information" is *not* in the list; pdb continues to work fine (this was not the case in earlier Python releases, where -O dropped support for single-stepping in pdb).

Comment: How much optimization can it really offer? Obviously, depends on the code, interpreter, environment, but perhaps some general comments apply?

Comment: @max: in general, I wouldn't expect any significant change in speed. Optimized byte code was originally designed to drop the inefficient SETLINENO byte code instruction, which was needed for single-stepping. However, single-stepping since got reimplemented using a more efficient approach, so -O has lost its point.

Comment: At least in current CPython versions, `__debug__` doesn't just get changed to `False`, any code under `if __debug__` is entirely stripped out.

Comment: the same behaviour for Python 3?

Comment: Same for python 3 as far as I know, though I believe the new object model allows for even more inlining of  `__debug__`-based control flows.. Don't quote me on it ;)  Either way, it should be pretty similar. Some things cpy2 can't (or doesn't) optimize: short-circuit boolean operations, `if not __debug__`, inline `if` statements.