# Compiling .py files to .pyo without resorting to a wrapper script

Tags: python

i am looking into compiling quite a big set of python modules and packages to pyo. I know this is possible by either setting the PYTHONOPTIMIZE environment variable or by specifying -O on launch. I'd like to enforce pyo instead of pyc to yield the smallest footprint possible. In order to do that in my deploy module i have to create a wrapper script that launches the actual script with the -O option, because the environment variable needs to be specified prior to starting the interpreter.

Is there any way around this and enforce pyo creation programmatically?

Kind regards,
Thorsten

Answer (score 24):

To *compile* all modules beforehand, run the following command:

```
python -O -m compileall /path/to/your/files
```

The [python `compileall` module](http://docs.python.org/library/compileall.html) takes care of the compilation, the [`-O` switch](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html?highlight=#cmdoption-O) makes it output .pyo files.

However, you cannot force Python to use these unless the `-O` switch is given for every run *or* the [`PYTHONOPTIMIZE` environment var](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html?highlight=#envvar-PYTHONOPTIMIZE) is set.

Note that all the -O flag does is disable the `assert` statement and set the `__debug__` flag to `False` (and Python will optimise out the tests). Specify -OO and docstrings are dropped. These do not make for much speed difference or space savings, unless you used excessive docstring sizes or very slow debug code.

See: [What does Python optimization (-O or PYTHONOPTIMIZE) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777113/what-does-python-optimization-o-or-pythonoptimize-do)

Answer (score 6):

Sadly from version 3.5 the compile optimization only makes .pyc files, not .pyo

> Changed in version 3.5: The legacy parameter only writes out .pyc
>   files, not .pyo files no matter what the value of optimize is.

From https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/compileall.html