# Custom widget in pyside (python/Qt) won't show up

Tags: python, qt, widget, pyside

I am just trying my first prototype in pyside (python/Qt). The application itself starts up fine, creates a window with widgets according to my layout. Threads are started and execute, all fine. Except...

I want to enhance the GUI by adding some custom widget indicating the execution state of the threads. So I thought flashing LEDs would be fine for that. For this I try to implement a custom LED widget.

Remember that I currently try to *learn* python, so there might be some strange approaches in this. Anyway, here is the LED widgets class in its current state:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class LED(QtGui.QWidget):

    class Mode:
        STATIC_OFF   = 0
        STATIC_ON    = 1
        FLASH_SLOW   = 2
        FLASH_MEDIUM = 2
        FLASH_FAST   = 3

    class Color:
        BLACK  = '#000000'
        GREEN  = '#00FF00'
        RED    = '#FF0000'
        BLUE   = '#0000FF'
        YELLOW = '#FFFF00' 
        WHITE  = '#FFFFFF'

    mode   = Mode.STATIC_ON
    color  = Color.BLACK
    radius = 10
    status = False
    timer  = None

    outdated = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, mode, color, radius, parent=None):
        super(LED, self).__init__(parent)
        self.outdated.connect(self.update)
        self.setMode(mode,False)
        self.setColor(color,False)
        self.setRadius(radius,False)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.adjustAppearance)
        self.adjustAppearance()

    def getCenter(self):
        return QtCore.QPoint(self.radius, self.radius)

    def getBox(self):
        return QtCore.QRect(self.radius, self.radius)

    def setColor(self, color, update=True):
        assert color in (self.Color.GREEN,self.Color.RED,self.Color.BLUE,self.Color.YELLOW,self.Color.WHITE), "invalid color"
        self.color = color
        if update:
            self.adjustAppearance()

    def setMode(self, mode, update=True):
        assert mode in (self.Mode.STATIC_OFF,self.Mode.STATIC_ON,self.Mode.FLASH_SLOW,self.Mode.FLASH_MEDIUM,self.Mode.FLASH_FAST),"invalid mode"
        self.mode = mode
        if update:
            self.adjustAppearance()

    def setRadius(self, radius, update=True):
        assert isinstance(radius, int), "invalid radius type (integer)"
        assert 10<=radius<=100, "invalid radius value (0-100)"
        self.radius = radius
        if update:
            self.adjustAppearance()

    def switchOn(self):
        self.status = True
        self.adjustAppearance()

    def switchOff(self):
        self.status = False
        self.adjustAppearance()

    def adjustAppearance(self):
        if self.mode is self.Mode.STATIC_OFF:
            self.status = False
            self.timer.stop()
        elif self.mode is self.Mode.STATIC_ON:
            self.status = True
            self.timer.stop()
        elif self.mode is self.Mode.FLASH_SLOW:
            self.status = not self.status
            self.timer.start(200)
        elif self.mode is self.Mode.FLASH_SLOW:
            self.status = not self.status
            self.timer.start(500)
        elif self.mode is self.Mode.FLASH_SLOW:
            self.status = not self.status
            self.timer.start(1000)
            self.outdated.emit()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        self.drawWidget(event, painter)
        painter.end()

    def drawWidget(self, event, painter):
        if self.status:
            shade = QtGui.QColor(self.color).darker
        else:
            shade = QtGui.QColor(self.color).lighter
        #painter.setPen(QtGui.QColor('black'), 1, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QColor('black'))
        painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.RadialGradientPattern)
        painter.drawEllipse(self.getCenter(), self.radius, self.radius)
```

My problem is that the widget simply does not show when I add it to the windows layout. Other widgets (non-custome, plain Qt widgets) do show, so I gues it is not a question of creating the widget, not a question of how I use the widget. Nevertheless here is the (shortened) instanciation if the widget:

```
class View(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    ui = None

    def __init__(self, config, parent=None):
        log.debug("window setup")
        self.config = config
        super(View, self).__init__(parent)
        try:
            self.ui = self.Ui(self)
            self.setObjectName("appView")
            self.setWindowTitle("AvaTalk")
            self.show()
        except RuntimeError as e:
            log.error(e.message)

    class Ui(QtCore.QObject):

        # [...]
        iconDetector = None
        buttonDetector = None
        # [...]

        def __init__(self, window, parent=None):
            log.debug("ui setup")
            super(View.Ui, self).__init__(parent)
            self.window = window

            # central widget
            log.debug("widget setup")
            self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
            self.widgetLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)

            # create toolbars
            #self.createMenubar()
            #self.createCanvas()
            self.createToolbar()
            #self.createStatusbar()

            # visualize widget
            self.window.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

            # actions
            log.debug("actions setup")
            self.actionQuit = QtGui.QAction(self.window)
            self.actionQuit.setObjectName("actionQuit")
            self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionQuit)
            self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())

            log.debug("connections setup")
            QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionQuit, QtCore.SIGNAL("activated()"), self.window.close)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self.window)

        def createToolbar(self):
            log.debug("toolbar setup")
            self.toolbar = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
            self.toolbar.setObjectName("toolbar")
            self.toolbar.addStretch(1)
            # camera
            # detector
            self.iconDetector = LED(LED.Mode.STATIC_OFF,LED.Color.GREEN,10,self.window)
            self.buttonDetector = IconButton("Detector", "detector",self.window)
            self.toolbar.addWidget(self.iconDetector)
            self.toolbar.addWidget(self.buttonDetector)
            self.toolbar.addStretch(1)
            # analyzer
            # extractor
            # layout
            self.widgetLayout.addLayout(self.toolbar)
```

It might well be that the actual painting using QPainter is still nonsense. I did not yet come to test that: actually when testing I find that `isVisible()` returns `False` on the widget after the setup has completed. So I assume I miss a central point. Unfortunately I am unable to find out what I miss...

Maybe someone can spot my issue? Thanks !

Comment: I think you must call update() in paintEvent function.

Comment: @Reza I doubt that... Actually `painEvent()` is never called, which is a symptom of my problem. It is usually called (I read) when `update()` is triggered. So the other way 'round.

Comment: as I know paintEvent() called when a widget has a parent and goes to drawing, check your widget have show() function and if yes, call them in your class constructor (__init__()), hope this helps.

Comment: @Reza: Calling `show()` inside the constructor does not change anything, tried that before. Also I never saw a `show()` inside a custom widget in all the examples around. And the widget _does_ have a parent, I pass the containing widget as parent (the window in this case).

Comment: Can you paste your setup? Getting `False` from `isVisible` is odd, if this is added to a visible widget.

Comment: @Avaris: ok, I added the (shortened) instanciation of the widget to the question. It is the second code block. That stuff is shortened quite a lot to concentrate on the relevant bits. Hope the idea gets clear: a window, inside a layout that holds a toolbar, that toolbar holds some widgets, some of those are meant to be the LED widgets I have problems with. The window shows fine, also the widgets inside (buttons), but not the LED widgets. No error, just not visible.

Comment: @arkascha: It is important to provide a self-contained runnable example that demonstrates the issue. I can't run your setup without guessing certain things (`IconButton`, indentation error with `createToolbar`?, etc.). There is one issue with `LED`, but since I can't run your code, I can't be certain that you don't have other issues. Anyway, I'll write an answer for the issue that I'm certain.

Comment: @Avaris: right, corrected the indentation issue, thanks for pointing that out. It is the result of pasting code using tabs for indentation here at SO where I have to manually adjust it to show up readable. I very much apprechiate your attempt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to be careful when implementing custom widgets derived from `QWidget` is: `sizeHint` or `minimumSizeHint` for `QWidget` returns invalid `QSize` by default. This means, if it is added to a layout, depending on the other widgets, it will shrink to `0`. This effectively makes it 'not-visible'. Although, `isVisible` would still return `True`. Widget is 'visible', but it just doesn't have anything to show (0 size). So, if you're getting `False`, there is definitely another issue at hand.

So it is necessary to define these two methods with sensible sizes:

```
class LED(QtGui.QWidget):
    # ...

    def sizeHint(self):
        size = 2 * self.radius + 2
        return QtCore.QSize(size, size)

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        size = 2 * self.radius + 2
        return QtCore.QSize(size, size)
```

Note: There are other issues:

- Like defining `mode`, `color`, etc as class attributes and then overriding them with instance attributes. They won't break anything but they are pointless.
- `painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.RadialGradientPattern)` is wrong. You can't create a brush with `QtCore.Qt.RadialGradientPattern`. It is there, so that `brush.style()` can return something. If you want a gradient pattern you should create a brush with [`QGradient` constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbrush.html#QBrush-10).
- `if self.mode is self.Mode.STATIC_OFF`: comparing with `is` is wrong. `is` compares identity, you want `==` here. (also, `FLASH_SLOW` and `FLASH_MEDIUM` are both `2`)
- `assert` is for debugging and unit tests. You shouldn't use it in real code. Raise an exception if you want. Or have sensible `default`s, where invalid values would be replaced with that.

Comment: Ok, I will implement those methods. Although I am surprised: all the examples I found on the internet come _without_ these methods...

Comment: Additional points 1 and 3 are the result of me being a bloody python newbie. Thanks for pointing that stuff out, I will dig into it. Point 4 surprises me, but ok. I thought assert _does_ raise an exception and is just a shortcut for a conditional with explicit exception raising. Maybe I understood the documentation wrong. Maybe point 2 is my issue here, although I am surprised that I do not get a warning or error. I will look into it, thanks. But before all I will invest time in a stripped down wrapper that uses my classes. I will post that example.

Comment: @arkascha: Regarding those examples, it depends. If the widget is intended to be a window, it doesn't need those methods. If it's a subwidget in a layout, it _should_ implement those methods. I can't say more without seeing the examples. As for `assert`, it does raise an exception. But it is usually used in unit tests. If you want to raise an exception, you should raise an appropriate one (like `ValueError`). `assert` in regular code is generally, bad practice. Also python has `-O` (optimization) flag which [will skip `assert`s](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4777156/843822).

Comment: I made a stripped down version:  https://cloud.christian-reiner.info/public.php?service=files&t=9190e830b594e9752b144beb9cc8df46 I know it is not fine not to post an example, but that is simply too much code... Even after I removed all classes and stuff not required for this test.

Comment: @arkascha: #2 creates a warning here: `QBrush: Wrong use of a gradient pattern`. And, it doesn't work (no gradient), which is not surprising actually, since gradients require additional parameters.

Comment: @arkascha: Well, #2 creates the warning _after_ `*Hint` methods. Before it's simply a `0` size widget and it doesn't have anything to paint. So `paintEvent` (including that line) is not executed.

Comment: Ok, that Brush initialization is a test result. Originally it was called using `shade` which is defined right above as a QColor. I reverted it back. Still no visible icon. However I did not see any warning before, so maybe I miss something there... What did you mean by "after `*Hint` methods"? Ah, wait, probably the two methods you mentioned...

Comment: Ah!! After adding those `*Hint` methods at least `painEvent()` is executed! Throws warnings and errors, but is executed! That is great!

Comment: Bringo! Adding the two `*Hint` methods and correcting the QBrush initialization finally shows the icons! Ugly as hell, but that's fine cause it is a starting point. And its a quick-n-dirty prototype anyway... So: thanks for the great help!

Comment: @arkascha: Glad it helped. Have fun :).