# Detect from a running python script if the optimize flag is -O or -OO

Tags: python, flags, sys

Sometime I'd like to spawn a child process with the same optimization flags used to start the parent.

I can use something like:

`optimize = not __debug__`

But this way I match both `-O` and `-OO` flags.

Is there some python internal status that contains that info?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some digging in the documentation I've found that the `sys.flags` struct sequence (http://docs.python.org/dev/library/sys#sys.flags) that has an `optimize` attribute containing  the information I was searching for.

`python -c "import sys; print sys.flags.optimize"` -> `0`

`python -O -c "import sys; print sys.flags.optimize"` -> `1`

`python -OO -c "import sys; print sys.flags.optimize"` -> `2`