# Python function call speed

Tags: python, optimization

I'm really confused with functions call speed in Python. First and second cases, nothing unexpected:

```
%timeit reduce(lambda res, x: res+x, range(1000))
```

> 10000 loops, best of 3: 150 µs per loop

```
def my_add(res, x):
return res + x
%timeit reduce(my_add, range(1000))
```

> 10000 loops, best of 3: 148 µs per loop

But third case looks strange for me:

```
from operator import add
%timeit reduce(add, range(1000))
```

> 10000 loops, best of 3: 80.1 µs per loop

At the same time:

```
%timeit add(10, 100)
%timeit 10 + 100

10000000 loops, best of 3: 94.3 ns per loop
100000000 loops, best of 3: 14.7 ns per loop
```

So, why the third case gives speed up about 50%?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`add` is implemented in C.

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> add
<built-in function add>
>>> def my_add(res, x):
...     return res + x
... 
>>> my_add
<function my_add at 0x18358c0>
```

The reason that a straight `+` is faster is that `add` still has to call the Python VM's `BINARY_ADD` instruction as well as perform some other work due to it being a function, while `+` is *only* a `BINARY_ADD` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

> The operator module exports a set of **efficient functions** corresponding to the intrinsic operators of Python. For example, operator.add(x, y) is equivalent to the expression x+y. The function names are those used for special class methods; variants without leading and trailing __ are also provided for convenience.

From [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

The [operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module is an efficient (native I'd assume) implementation. IMHO, calling a native implementation should be quicker than calling a python function.

You could try calling the interpreter with `-O` or `-OO` to [compile](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#compiled-python-files) the python core and check the timing again.

Comment: All Python code gets compiled to bytecode, `-O` just strips debugging instructions like `assert` and `if __debug__` blocks.

Comment: You're right. I was under the false impression that -O would do the same as gcc. This happens in [pypy](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/config/opt.html). Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777113/what-does-python-optimization-o-or-pythonoptimize-do).