# what does PYTHONOPTIMIZE do in the python interpreter?

Tags: python, environment-variables, supervisord

I run a python task with supervisor, and when I try to use mutilprocess in the python task.I meet with the error

```
"File/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 124, in start 

'daemonic processes are not allowed to have children'"
```

But that's okay after I execute the command `"export PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1"` in the terminal .Anyone can tell me what has happened while executing the command `"export PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1"`

Comment: export is used to set environment variables in linux based systems

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777113/what-does-python-optimization-o-or-pythonoptimize-do

Answer (score 6):

Setting the [`PYTHONOPTIMIZE` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONOPTIMIZE) to `1` is the same thing as using the [`-O` command line switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-o):

> Remove assert statements and any code conditional on the value of `__debug__`.

The error message you see is an `AssertionError` exception; the [relevant section of the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/35f9bccd8198330579ecb4b4c503062f8b5da130/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L123-L124) uses `assert`:

```
assert not _current_process._daemonic, \
       'daemonic processes are not allowed to have children'
```

so setting the environment variable only suppresses the assertion. The problem itself doesn't go away.