# PYTHONOPTIMIZE in an IPython/Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How do I disable assertions and docstrings, respectively, in an IPython session or a Jupyter Notebook?

After [the official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONOPTIMIZE), [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4777113) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57493983) to a similar question, I may “set the `PYTHONOPTIMIZE` environment variable to `1`”. Well, if I set the environment variable following [this blog post](https://blog.softhints.com/how-to-set-environmental-variable-in-jupyter-notebook/) via

```
%env PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1
```

I can successfully list the value along all other variables with `%env`, but still unexpectedly `__debug__ == True` and `AssertionError`s are raised. Different values like `2` or a string `"1"` weren't successful, either.

*Bonus question*: Is it possible to disable `assert` only for a specific (local) library, like after using `import myfancylib`, `myfancylib.eggs()` won't `raise`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to disable `assert` only for the currently active session. However, there are a couple of other options.

Non volatile disable `assert` for current conda environment:

```
_disable_assert = True
_disable_assert_msg = "To make your changes take effect please Save and restart Jupyter Notebook\n"
if _disable_assert:
    try:
        assert False
        print("OK - assert disabled")
    except AssertionError:
        import os
        import sys
        
        os.system("conda env config vars set PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1")
        print(_disable_assert_msg, file=sys.stderr)
        assert False, _disable_assert_msg
else:
    try:
        assert False

        import os
        import sys

        os.system("conda env config vars unset PYTHONOPTIMIZE")
        print(_disable_assert_msg, file=sys.stderr)
        _zero_division = 1/0
    except AssertionError:
        print("OK - assert enabled")
```

Disable `assert` for cell:

```
%%python -O 
# Only for one cell. This cell is run in a separate process.

import sys
import os

print(__debug__)
print(sys.argv)
print(os.environ)

try:
    assert False
    print("Assert disable")
except AssertionError:
    print("Assert enable")
```

Comment: You mean just setting a global variable `_disable_assert = True` works?

Comment: @aaron, Sorry, I didn't understand your question. `_disable_assert` and `_disable_assert_msg` are internal variables of this code snippet. They start with `_` to reduce the likelihood of conflict with other parts of the code.

Comment: @aaron, There are several ways to set the `PYTHONOPTIMIZE` variable before starting python: command-line utilities, editing configuration files, etc. Personally, I find this method of change convenient, directly in notepad. It seems that the author of the question was also looking for something similar to `%env`.

Comment: Ah, it would be clearer to define that in a function `def set_disable_alert(disable_assert):`. Your code snippet as-is appears to imply that setting the global variable `_disable_assert = True` disables assert.