# What are the optimization levels in Cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, optimization, cx-freeze

I'm freezing my scripts with Cx_Freeze 6.0 (Python 3.7.4 64 bit if that makes any difference) and I'm struggling to find any documentation about the optimization levels in `build_exe`. Most scripts I see use either `1` or no value at all, I've used `1` and `2` successfully and I can't spot any difference in the exe.

My current options look something like this:

```
exe_options = {
    'build_exe': 'bin',
    'includes': ['something'],
    'excludes': ['something_else'],
    'packages': ['pack', 'age'],
    'optimize': 2  # What the hell are the levels?
}
```

Edit: I checked an MD5 hash and a SHA-256 hash on the exe files, with levels 0,1 and 2, the exe is the exact same file. Is this option just unused when running "build"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has the same effect as the [`-O` command line option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-o) when executing CPython directly. Among [other things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777113/what-does-python-optimization-o-or-pythonoptimize-do#4777156), it prevents `assert` statements from executing, remove docstrings and set `__debug__` to `False`.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why the results are identical for exe files built with different levels. If `__debug__` is set to `False`, for example, shouldn't the exe hash be different?

Comment: Did you try freezing with code that actually depends on `__debug__`? You can also query `sys.flags.optimize`, which should give back the value you passed to `cx_freeze`.