# Is there a way to share VS Code breakpoints with other developers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1698167/6380791) trick and I like the idea of having the ability to have blocks of code run only in a debug configuration, but when I tried using it I ended up with a lot of lines looking like this:

```py
if __debug__: logging.debug('started some work')
```

Sadly, it clutters the code significantly.
VS Code's [logpoints](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_logpoints) are much more elegant way to do it, but I couldn't find a way to check them into version control, nor find how they are saved.
Is it possible to somehow share VS Code's breakpoints/logpoints with others?

Comment: Using `__debug__` and `logging.debug` is somewhat redundant.

Comment: How so? The point of `if __debug__:` is to remove the block that follows from production code. I believe `logging.debug` is still present in the bytecode even if the logger has a different logging level enabled. Am I wrong?

Comment: breakpoints are placed by line number, if you pull and merge from team members and you open your project the breakpoints can be placed on the wrong lines

Comment: @Harvastum Can you tell us if my answer solved your question and which of the three suggested methods works for you?

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I know to archive something similar to share the breakpoints is to create a collaborative debug session. Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/use/vscode#co-debugging), I have found relevant information:

> Each collaborator can investigate different variables, jump to
> different files in the call stack, inspect variables, and even add or
> remove breakpoints. Co-editing features then allow each participant
> orator to track where the others are located to provide the unique
> ability to seamlessly switch between concurrently investigating
> different aspects of the problem and collaboratively debugging.
>
> Using it is simple.
>
> 1. Be sure both the host and all guests have the appropriate debugging extension installed. (Technically this is not always
>    necessary, but it is generally a good idea.)
> 2. As the host, if not already set up for the project, you should configure launch.json to debug the application from VS Code as you
>    would normally. No special setup is required.
> 3. Next, the host can start debugging using the button in the debug tab as normal.

You can easily setup what you need following the [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/use/vscode)

---

In case you want another alternative take a look at [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deckerio.breakpointio), I have never tested it but it seems what you need.

---

Someone has created an [issue on GitHub for this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/14314), but it seems to be dead.